# How can I factorize this: "$X^3 + X^2 + X - 3$"

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am going to elementary school & I am living in one of those deprived areas of Africa.

I can solve mathematical questions like this:

$$X^3 + X^2 + X +1 = X^2(X+1)+(X+1) = (X+1)(X^2+1)$$

Or even

\begin{align}X^2 − 2X + X^2 - X + 1 &= (X^2 - 2X + 1) + (X^2 - X) \\
&= (X - 1)^2 + X(X - 1) \\
&= (X-1)(X-1+X) \\
&= (X - 1)(2X - 1)
\end{align}

But for a few months I have not been able to find a teacher around here who can factorize this:

$$X^3 + X^2 + X - 3$$

Do we have to solve it in this way?

$$X^3 + X^2 + X - 3 = X^2(X + 1) + X - 3$$

Or something else?
I'd appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Hint: $x=1$ is a root of your polynomial, meaning that the polynomial is divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: $X^3+X^2+X-3  = X^3-1 + X^2-1 + X-1 = (X-1)(X^2+X+1)+(X-1)(X+1)+(X-1) = (X-1)(X^2+2X+3)$, $X^2+2X+3$ you can't factorize when working with real numbers

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi You might want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Excuse me, this question may seem strange or silly, but I do not know how to use this MathJox. I'm new to this, where should I start from?

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi  The “[MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)” in my previous comment is actually a hyperlink to the tutorial. Click on it and go from there

Answer (score 4):

Surely $1$ is a root of $x^3+x^2+x-3$ therefore $x-1$ is a factor of it. We have $$x^3+x^2+x-3=(x-1)(x^2+x+1+x+1+1)=(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)$$

Comment: I will show this to my teacher, he maybe recall, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $(x^3+x^2+x-3):(x-1)=x^2+2x+3$

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of problem it is worth knowing about the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

This says if $a$ is a root of your polynomial $f(x)$ i.e. $f(a)=0$ then $x-a$ is a factor of, i.e. divides, the polynomial.

In these kinds of problems it is worth trying a few values such as $\pm1, \pm2$.

In your example $f(1)=0$ so $x-1$ divides your polynomial, allowing you to factorize it as $(x-1)(Ax^2+Bx+C)$ where you need to find $A,B,C$.

Comment: Useful, I can't adequately express my gratefulness!

Comment: Thank-you. I am very pleased it helped you.